# Have lubridate subtraction return only a numeric value

Tags: r, date, package, lubridate

I have one variable called `Started` which is the date on which human subjects enrolled in a study and another variable called `dos1` which is the date upon which the subject last had surgery. I want to work out how many months since their last surgery to the day of enrollment.  I tried:

```
as.period(syrrupan$Started-syrrupan$dos1,units=c("month"))
```

I expected this to give me something like:

```
14, 18, 1, 26
```

With each number being the number of months.

Instead I get:

```
1 year, -4 months, -5 days and -1 hours   1 year, -5 months, -23 days and -1 hours   1 year, -7 months, 2 days and -1 hours   1 year, -8 months, -28 days and 1 hour   1 year, -7 months, -23 days and 1 hour.
```

How can I get just the numeric value of months?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could try using `difftime` instead, ie:

```
difftime(syrrupan$Started,syrrupan$dos1,units="days")
```

Note that this will give you an object of class `difftime`, if you want a numeric vector, wrap an `as.numeric` around it. Note also that you can't choose months as an option for units, but you should really stick with a time unit that has a fixed length.

Comment: In that case you could just divide the above result by 30.44.

Comment: difftime is from the base package. Since the columns were "Date" I was also able to simply enter   syrrupan$Started-syrrupan$dos1 which created a vector of class "difftime" in days. By the way, the syntax of difftime does not permit the minus sign, rather it should be just a comma. To get months and to have just one significant value after the decimal I used   round(as.numeric(difftime(syrrupan$Started,syrrupan$dos1,units="days"))/30.44,1). In lubridate I was able to do this round(as.numeric(as.duration(syrrupan$Started-syrrupan$dos1))/60/60/24/30.44,1) which seems clunky.

Comment: Sorry, yes the minus sign crept in when I copied your variable names from the question. I've fixed the answer now.

Comment: Didn't help when I needed a difference in years. See `time_length()` instead, as suggested below.

Answer (score 11):

As noted in [R - lubridate - Convert Period into numeric counting months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994272/r-lubridate-convert-period-into-numeric-counting-months) the intended lubridate method here would be `time_length`

```
time_length(syrrupan$Started-syrrupan$dos1, unit="days")
```

Comment: Also see https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/906

Comment: This merits a higher rating.

Answer (score 7):

That's definitely a bug in lubridate. I've made an error report and will fix it for version 0.1:

http://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues#issue/75

Thanks for bringing it to my attention.