# How to convert specific time string to numeric variable?

Tags: r, string

I have data which represents age, it is given as for example `8y 10m 27d`, where `y` are years, `m` are months, and `d` are days.

I've tried using `gsub()` to replace the `y`, `m` and `d` with `*365+`, `*30+` and nothing respectively, and then using `as.numeric()`, but R doesn't know that it should calculate first so it just returns NA.

Is there a way to convert that kind of string to the exact number of days?

Sorry for the formatting, I can't remember the last time I was on this site so I forgot how to format.

Comment: You can have a look at the lubridate package
e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765668/have-lubridate-subtraction-return-only-a-numeric-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn` to replace the 'y', 'm', 'd' with the "* 365 +", "* 30 + " and "* 1" and evaluate the string with `eval(parse(.`

```
library(gsubfn)
eval(parse(text=gsubfn("[a-z]", list(y= "* 365 + ", m = "* 30 + ", d = "* 1"), str1)))
#[1] 3247
```

---

Or a faster option would be

```
c(matrix(scan(text=sub(",$", "", gsub("\\D+", ",", str2)), sep=",",
    what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE) %*% c(365, 30, 1))
#[1] 3247 3247
```

#### Update

If there are different patterns in the dataset, we can try

```
str3 <- c(str1, "7m 28d", "5y 10d", "15d", "29d", "8y 15d 10m" )
colSums(sapply(strsplit(str3, "\\s+"), function(x) {
          x1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", x))
           x2 <- sub("\\d+", "", x)
         x1[match(c("y", "m", "d"), x2)]}) * c(365, 30, 1), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3247  238 1835   15   29 3235
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "8y 10m 27d"
str2 <- c(str1, str1)
```

Comment: And how would I modify this to work on an entire data set? Just use a for loop or?

Comment: @implicati0n  You can use `sapply(str1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`

Comment: I get an error "Error in parse ... unexpected end of input". @akrun

Comment: @implicati0n  I tried with `str2 <- c(str1, str1); unname(sapply(gsubfn("[a-z]", list(y= "* 365 + ", m = "* 30 + ", d = "* 1"), str2), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
#[1] 3247 3247`

Comment: @implicati0n  Are you saying the error using the same `str2` or your original dataset.  Please check if your dataset have different patterns etc.

Comment: @implicati0n  I also added another method.

Comment: Sorry, the error occurs when I work with my dataset. Unfortunately, it does have different patterns, some data are missing "m" or "d", however, the error occurs on a data which is of the form with all three letters. @akrun

Comment: @implicati0n  Sorry, this is based on what you showed in the post.

Comment: I know, it was my mistake, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @implicati0n  Updated with another option for different patterns.

Comment: Using the command from the 4th comment, I get what I needed when I remove the data which isn't of the needed form. However, how can I assign this to a new variable? Because when I try to print str2, I get the unchanged version of it.

Comment: @implicati0n  You need to assign i.e. `res <- colSums(sapply(strsplit(str3, "\\s+"), function(x) {
          x1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", x))
           x2 <- sub("\\d+", "", x)
         x1[match(c("y", "m", "d"), x2)]}) * c(365, 30, 1), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in "res <- colSums(sapply(strsplit(baza$Age, "\\s+"), function(x) { x1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", x)) x2"

Sorry, but I'm new to R so I'm really struggling.

Comment: @implicati0n  Sorry, I was copying from the code.  You have to use the `;` separator for each line. i.e. `{ x1 <- as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", x));  x2 <- sub("\\d+", "", x);x1[match(c("y", "m", "d"), x2)]}) * c(365, 30, 1), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution can depend on the origin date (because of leap years)

A solution can be:

```
str="8y 10m 27d"
str2=gsub("[A-z]","",str)
str3=as.numeric(strsplit(str2, " ")[[1]])
date1=origin=as.POSIXlt("1990-01-01")
date1$year=date1$year+str3[1]
date1$mon=date1$mon+str3[2]
date1$mday=date1$mday+str3[3]
date1-origin
#[1] Time difference of 3253 days
```